# What is this that (probably) came off a 2002 Ford Ka

Tags: ford, part-identification, ka

I moved my car and noticed this thing where it was parked. I'm not sure what it is but think there's quite a high probability that it came from my car. Since this has happened I've noticed that there's a knocking noise if I hit a bump a bit too hard that I don't think was there before. I've looked at some diagrams for the suspension but couldn't see anything that matches. Does anyone know what it is? There's an open ended cylinder that has a threaded thing coming out of it. The closed end has a small hole where something has sheared off and there would be a wire coming through. The other end of that wire is tied into a ball on the inside of the cylinder. The car is standard UK spec.

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]

Comment: Possible part of the evaporative emissions.

Comment: This looks like it has been out in the weather and beat up on the road/parking lot for some time.  A motor like this I do not think would be exposed to this type of abuse if still fitted to your car so I do not think it fell from your car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of an electric motor, I'm not sure what from though- I'd guess perhaps not automotive, the size suggests something like an electric drill or similar.

Are there any numbers stamped or engraved on the casing?

Comment: Since it has a worm drive on the shaft it is unlikely to be off a drill, but I agree it is a small motor.  I could imagine it being out of a window winder or a sun roof off a car.

Comment: Agreed @HandyHowie - I could see this as part of the window regulator as well. This would not have just fallen out by happenstance, though. It would have needed some help to get out of its place of residence.